# How to print scientific notation numbers in custom format using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a set of scientific notation numbers (***x***), shown in **column 1** in the table below. I am trying to print the numbers in custom format as shown in **column 3** using PHP. How can I do it so? I tried `printf("%.0e", $x);` and `print sprintf("%.0e", $x);`, but got result as shown in **column 2**.

Please somebody help me to solve the problem.

[image: Scientific Notation Number]

Comment: *"I am trying to print the numbers in custom format as shown in column 3"* -- the numbers in column 3 are not formatted according to only one format but at least three: the usual notation (`9.6`), the usual scientific notation (`1e-76`) and a "custom" scientific notation (`7e-04`). PHP is not able to read your mind. You should set some thresholds and use different formatting strings for each interval of values. Read about the [formatting specifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters) for the `printf()`/`sprintf()` functions.

Comment: The `g` format specifier might be your friend here. It generates whatever gives the shortest result string after applying both formats `%e`and `%f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the output was generated by NCBI BLAST server using CGI script. After many trials, I found a new method to solve the problem. But, I am still surprised... whether there is solution using Perl/CGI.

```
<?php
function efmt($Hsp_evalue) {
    $x = (float)sprintf("%.1e", $Hsp_evalue);
    if (preg_match("/e-/i", $x)) {
        $y = explode("E-", $x);
        if ($y[1] < 10) return round($y[0]) . "e-0" . $y[1];
        else return round($y[0]) . "e-" . $y[1];
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/\./", $x)) {
            if ($x * 1000 < 1) return round($x * 10000) . "e-04";
            else return $x;
        } else
            return $x . ".0";
    }
}

print efmt("9.58544"); // Output: 9.6
?>
```